# Unable to open database in WordPress

Tags: database, wordpress

I've created a new database in Wordpress, but I'm unable to access it:

PHP code:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect     to '$dbhost'");
mysqli_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");
```

I'm getting the 'Could not open the db' message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that db name exists? And that the dbuser you are using has access to it?

Comment: Yes and yes. I can access it using cPanel and phpMyAdmin with that user and password.

Comment: `mysqli_select_db` use 2 parameters on the procedural style. First must be the connection

Comment: Good spotting @Sysix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass , $dbname) or die("Unable to Connect to database" );

$sql="SELECT * FROM  yourtablename";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {

  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1];

    }

  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I tried that and it comes back with 'There are no tables'. It appears the connection is completed but I'm unable to open or access the database.

Comment: Additional info: This is from a sub-domain. I've tried this from a WordPress sub-domain and a non-WordPress sub-domain.

Comment: @user2828527 I edited my code its a exmaple to connect database and fecth your rows from yourtable